# How to edit Realm Object Server configuration on Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, realm

I deployed Realm Object Server on Amazon EC2 instance with AMI. Now I want to edit configuration file to enable facebook auth, but I can't figure out how I can do this? I connected to my instance with SSH and I didn't found any realm connected files. I am very new to EC2, so can you give me some advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to edit the configuration.yml file found in the `/etc/realm` folder - and then restart the realm-object-server process

Comment: so maybe I forget about something but when I connect to my Ec2 instance via ssh i havn't /etc/realm folder

Comment: Can you start the service with `systemctl start realm-object-server` ?